# Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на один элемент, все остальные элементы в аккордеоне вовсе исчезали

Tags: html, jquery, css, веб-программирование

Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на один элемент, все остальные элементы в аккордеоне вовсе исчезали.

Вот скрипт самого аккордиона

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //прикрепляем клик по заголовкам acc-head
 $('#accordeon .acc-head').on('click', f_acc);
});
 
function f_acc(){
//скрываем все кроме того, что должны открыть
  $('#accordeon .acc-body').not($(this).next()).slideUp(1000);
// открываем или скрываем блок под заголовком, по которому кликнули
    $(this).next().slideToggle(1000);
}
```

```css
#accordeon {
 width: 350px;
 border: 10px solid #fff;
 box-shadow: 0 0 10px grey;
 margin: 10px;
}
 
.acc-head {
 padding: 5px 10px;
 background: #c0c0c0;
 cursor: pointer;
}
 
.acc-body {
 padding: 10px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="accordeon">
  <div class="acc-head">
   Заголовок 1
  </div>
  <div class="ac-body">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum saepe ex nesciunt, quidem quis illo cupiditate, quod maxime. Tenetur, ex quos. Magnam quasi iure facere minus velit voluptate accusamus hic!
  </div>
  <div class="acc-head">
   Заголовок 1
  </div>
  <div class="acc-body">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum saepe ex nesciunt, quidem quis illo cupiditate, quod maxime. Tenetur, ex quos. Magnam quasi iure facere minus velit voluptate accusamus hic!
  </div>
  <div class="acc-head">
   Заголовок 1
  </div>
  <div class="acc-body">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum saepe ex nesciunt, quidem quis illo cupiditate, quod maxime. Tenetur, ex quos. Magnam quasi iure facere minus velit voluptate accusamus hic!
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: в каком смысле исчезали? чтобы скрывались или чтобы закрывались остальные?

Comment: Чтобы скрывались

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#accordeon .acc-head').on('click', function(){
     var elem = $( this ),
        all_body = $( ".acc-body" ),
        current_body = elem.parent().find( ".acc-body" );
   
     //all_body.slideUp(1000);
     $( ".acc-head" ).not( this ).parent().hide();
     current_body.slideDown(1000);
     
  });
});
```

```css
#accordeon {
 width: 350px;
 border: 10px solid #fff;
 box-shadow: 0 0 10px grey;
 margin: 10px;
}
 
.acc-head {
 padding: 5px 10px;
 background: #c0c0c0;
 cursor: pointer;
}
 
.acc-body {
 padding: 10px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="accordeon">
    <div class="accordeon-item">
      <div class="acc-head">
        Заголовок 1
      </div>
      <div class="acc-body">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum saepe ex nesciunt, quidem quis illo cupiditate, quod maxime. Tenetur, ex quos. Magnam quasi iure facere minus velit voluptate accusamus hic!
      </div>
    </div>
  <div class="accordeon-item">
      <div class="acc-head">
        Заголовок 1
      </div>
      <div class="acc-body">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum saepe ex nesciunt, quidem quis illo cupiditate, quod maxime. Tenetur, ex quos. Magnam quasi iure facere minus velit voluptate accusamus hic!
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordeon-item">
      <div class="acc-head">
        Заголовок 1
      </div>
      <div class="acc-body">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum saepe ex nesciunt, quidem quis illo cupiditate, quod maxime. Tenetur, ex quos. Magnam quasi iure facere minus velit voluptate accusamus hic!
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: А можна сделать чтобы все остальные элементы вовсе исчезали.

Comment: @ArtemDikarev поправил код, но, не пойму зачем вам тогда аккордеон тут...